# PHP - Array - Access siblings/child key values based on key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Have this array (as JSON):

```
{
  "token_name": "C_ROOT",
  "token_group": "C_BLOCK",
  "group": true,
  "body": [
    [
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
        "token": 320,
        "value": "sort",
        "line": 2,
        "token_group": "VARIABLES",
        "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
      },
      {
        "token_name_org": "C_ASSIGNMENT_EQUAL",
        "line": 2,
        "value": "=",
        "token": "VALUE",
        "token_group": "ASSIGNMENTS"
      },
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
        "token": 320,
        "value": "_GET",
        "line": 2,
        "token_group": "VARIABLES",
        "token_name": "C_VARIABLE",
        "args": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING",
              "token": 323,
              "value": "sort",
              "line": 2,
              "token_group": "STRINGS",
              "token_name": "C_STRING"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Wrote this code to search for key "value" being "sort".

```
    public function search_var($array,$var)
    {


        foreach($array as $key=>$value)
        {

            if(is_array($value))
            {

                $this->search_var($value,$var);

            }else{
                if(isset($array["value"]) && $array["value"] == $var)
                {
                    print $value."\n";
                }   


            }

        }

    }

  print_r($scanner->search_var($map,"sort"));
```

Don't know how can I reference in my code the siblings and childs? I.e

Now the output is:

```
T_VARIABLE
320
sort
2
VARIABLES
C_VARIABLE
```

How can I make it that I see as output only:

```
/sort/=/_GET/sort
```

Each value between "/" is a key "value" in sibling or child (last case)

Thanks,

Comment: how can the output be `/sort/=/_GET/sort` when you only search for the one array having  `value='sort'`?

Comment: and the function doesn't return anything, so the last line will not print anything

Comment: I'm struggling to see how you wrote a recursive function and were then unable to select the keys and values.  Is this a homework question?

Comment: @axiac yes that's correct. I would like to output all the values key value seperated by "/" including sibligns childs, and child's child etc

Comment: The array posted in the question defines only one path (`/sort/=/_GET/sort`). How should the function work if multiple paths are possible? For example, if the content of `body` is duplicated and the values associated with the `value` key are modified?

Comment: I hope this answers your question. The array will be normalized (Tree structure). If there is a new element in body it will be the new branch (with its parent, children and leaves). The will be only one body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the question what to return when `body` contains more information than the one posted in the question. This answers assumes it never does.

A possible solution is to use `array_walk_recursive()` and collect the values associated with the `value` keys into an array. After the walk, the collected values are simply joined using the desired separator (`/`):

```
$text = '{"token_name":"C_ROOT","token_group":"C_BLOCK","group":true,"body":[[{"token_name_org":"T_VARIABLE","token":320,"value":"sort","line":2,"token_group":"VARIABLES","token_name":"C_VARIABLE"},{"token_name_org":"C_ASSIGNMENT_EQUAL","line":2,"value":"=","token":"VALUE","token_group":"ASSIGNMENTS"},{"token_name_org":"T_VARIABLE","token":320,"value":"_GET","line":2,"token_group":"VARIABLES","token_name":"C_VARIABLE","args":[[{"token_name_org":"T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING","token":323,"value":"sort","line":2,"token_group":"STRINGS","token_name":"C_STRING"}]]}],[{"token_name_org":"T_VARIABLE","token":320,"value":"mort","line":2,"token_group":"VARIABLES","token_name":"C_VARIABLE"},{"token_name_org":"C_ASSIGNMENT_EQUAL","line":2,"value":"=","token":"VALUE","token_group":"ASSIGNMENTS"},{"token_name_org":"T_VARIABLE","token":320,"value":"_GET","line":2,"token_group":"VARIABLES","token_name":"C_VARIABLE","args":[[{"token_name_org":"T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING","token":323,"value":"mort","line":2,"token_group":"STRINGS","token_name":"C_STRING"}]]}]]}';

$array = json_decode($text, TRUE);


// Collect the values here.
// Start with an empty string to force a leading '/' in the output
$path = array('');
// Walk the array, put the desired values in $path
array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function($value, $key) use (&$path) {      // use reference to modify $path inside the function
        if ($key == 'value') {
            $path[] = $value;
        }
    }
);

// Join the collected values and output the result
echo(implode('/', $path));
```

Comment: Almost perfect answer!!!! Thanks!! Wouldnt figure it out. Just small question: How to make that each Path is displayed in new line i.e Now it is: "/sort/=/_GET/sort/mort/=/_GET/mort" need it to be "/sort/=/_GET/sort\n/mort/=/_GET/mort"

Comment: Also if you read this, a search key value should be also a parameter i.e I want to do this only for "sort", when first element has key "value" with value "sort" it than should build the path till the end, others should be ignored

Comment: Hard to explain this :) Thanks for your help anyway. Got me further

Comment: Openend new question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699113/php-array-recursively-print-each-full-branch-up-to-leaf-leaves-of-the-nest

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very badly worded but I believe you are trying to achieve this:

```
public function search_var($array,$var) {
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $this->search_var($value,$var);
        } elseif($key == $var) {
            print "/".$value;
        }
    }
}
```