# PHP - Array - Recursively print each full branch (up to leaf/leaves) of the nested array (Tree) as an Xpath

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Have this code:

```
$text = '{"token_name":"C_ROOT","token_group":"C_BLOCK","group":true,"body":[[{"token_name_org":"T_VARIABLE","token":320,"value":"sort","line":2,"token_group":"VARIABLES","token_name":"C_VARIABLE"},{"token_name_org":"C_ASSIGNMENT_EQUAL","line":2,"value":"=","token":"VALUE","token_group":"ASSIGNMENTS"},{"token_name_org":"T_VARIABLE","token":320,"value":"_GET","line":2,"token_group":"VARIABLES","token_name":"C_VARIABLE","args":[[{"token_name_org":"T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING","token":323,"value":"sort","line":2,"token_group":"STRINGS","token_name":"C_STRING"}]]}],[{"token_name_org":"T_VARIABLE","token":320,"value":"mort","line":2,"token_group":"VARIABLES","token_name":"C_VARIABLE"},{"token_name_org":"C_ASSIGNMENT_EQUAL","line":2,"value":"=","token":"VALUE","token_group":"ASSIGNMENTS"},{"token_name_org":"T_VARIABLE","token":320,"value":"_GET","line":2,"token_group":"VARIABLES","token_name":"C_VARIABLE","args":[[{"token_name_org":"T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING","token":323,"value":"mort","line":2,"token_group":"STRINGS","token_name":"C_STRING"}]]}],[{"token_name_org":"T_VARIABLE","token":320,"value":"bort","line":2,"token_group":"VARIABLES","token_name":"C_VARIABLE"},{"token_name_org":"C_ASSIGNMENT_EQUAL","line":2,"value":"=","token":"VALUE","token_group":"ASSIGNMENTS"},{"token_name_org":"T_VARIABLE","token":320,"value":"_GET","line":2,"token_group":"VARIABLES","token_name":"C_VARIABLE","args":[[{"token_name_org":"T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING","token":323,"value":"bort","line":2,"token_group":"STRINGS","token_name":"C_STRING"}]]}]]}';

$array = json_decode($text, TRUE);


// Collect the values here.
// Start with an empty string to force a leading '/' in the output
$path = array('');
// Walk the array, put the desired values in $path
array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function($value, $key) use (&$path) {      // use reference to modify $path inside the function
        if ($key == 'value' ) {
            $path[] = $value;
        }
    }
);

// Join the collected values and output the result
echo(implode('/', $path));
```

It goes through the Array (Tree) and prints Xpath for each branch, up to the leaves:

Prettified array as JSON:

```
{
  "token_name": "C_ROOT",
  "token_group": "C_BLOCK",
  "group": true,
  "body": [
    [
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
        "token": 320,
        "value": "sort",
        "line": 2,
        "token_group": "VARIABLES",
        "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
      },
      {
        "token_name_org": "C_ASSIGNMENT_EQUAL",
        "line": 2,
        "value": "=",
        "token": "VALUE",
        "token_group": "ASSIGNMENTS"
      },
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
        "token": 320,
        "value": "_GET",
        "line": 2,
        "token_group": "VARIABLES",
        "token_name": "C_VARIABLE",
        "args": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING",
              "token": 323,
              "value": "sort",
              "line": 2,
              "token_group": "STRINGS",
              "token_name": "C_STRING"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
        "token": 320,
        "value": "mort",
        "line": 2,
        "token_group": "VARIABLES",
        "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
      },
      {
        "token_name_org": "C_ASSIGNMENT_EQUAL",
        "line": 2,
        "value": "=",
        "token": "VALUE",
        "token_group": "ASSIGNMENTS"
      },
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
        "token": 320,
        "value": "_GET",
        "line": 2,
        "token_group": "VARIABLES",
        "token_name": "C_VARIABLE",
        "args": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING",
              "token": 323,
              "value": "mort",
              "line": 2,
              "token_group": "STRINGS",
              "token_name": "C_STRING"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
        "token": 320,
        "value": "bort",
        "line": 2,
        "token_group": "VARIABLES",
        "token_name": "C_VARIABLE"
      },
      {
        "token_name_org": "C_ASSIGNMENT_EQUAL",
        "line": 2,
        "value": "=",
        "token": "VALUE",
        "token_group": "ASSIGNMENTS"
      },
      {
        "token_name_org": "T_VARIABLE",
        "token": 320,
        "value": "_GET",
        "line": 2,
        "token_group": "VARIABLES",
        "token_name": "C_VARIABLE",
        "args": [
          [
            {
              "token_name_org": "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING",
              "token": 323,
              "value": "bort",
              "line": 2,
              "token_group": "STRINGS",
              "token_name": "C_STRING"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
/sort/=/_GET/sort/mort/=/_GET/mort/bort/=/_GET/bort
```

Anybody have an idea how can I count the number of nested arrays, know when to stop, where the branch ends? Also how can I specify to search only for "sort", branches "mort" and "bort" should not appear.

The output should be, based on search "sort":

```
/sort/=/_GET/sort
```

So the pseudocode should be I think something like this:

1. Find in "body" array with key "value" equal to what is search for (i.e "sort")
2. Get all the siblings and children, children's children etc key "value" value until the branch ends.
3. Print the branch
4. Goto 1 for next body item

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to identify that item of `body` that contains `value == 'sort'` then apply the existing code (extract it in a function first):

```
$search = 'sort';

// Identify the items having 'value' associated with $search
$allItems = array_filter(
    $array['body'],
    function (array $item) use ($search) {
        // $item contains many tokens, keep $item if the first token has value == 'sort'
        // just to be sure you can also check here if $item[0]['token'] is 320 or the value of 'token_org_name'
        return $item[0]['value'] == $search;
    }
);

// Pass all the found items to the function that produces the path
foreach ($allItems as $item) {
   echo(getPath($item)."\n");
}


function getPath(array $array) {
    // Collect the values here.
    // Start with an empty string to force a leading '/' in the output
    $path = array('');
    // Walk the array, put the desired values in $path
    array_walk_recursive(
        $array,
        function($value, $key) use (&$path) {
            if ($key == 'value' ) {
                $path[] = $value;
            }
        }
    );

    // Join the collected values and return the result
    return implode('/', $path);
}
```